# SQL statement filter result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to filter the SQL query result according to 3 conditions:
1. Location
2. Doctor Name
3. Specialty Name

Below is the sql query if all 3 conditions are not empty:

```
if (location != "" && doctor!="" && specialty!="")

select Location, ...
from clinicdoctors
where Location = @Location and DoctorName = @DoctorName and SpecialtyName = @SpecialtyName

}
```

if only location is empty,

```
if (location == "" && doctor!="" && specialty!="")
select Location, ...
from clinicdoctors
where Location is not null and DoctorName = @DoctorName and SpecialtyName = @SpecialtyName

...
```

If I wanna check all the conditions, I need to write eight if statements.
What should I do to simplify the code in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

```
select Location, ...
from clinicdoctors
where 
 ISNULL(@Location,Location) = Location
 and ISNULL(@DoctorName,DoctorName) = DoctorName
 and ISNULL(@SpecialtyName,SpecialtyName) = SpecialtyName
```

Comment: Look into the ISNULL keyword.

Comment: Whoops. Yeah. That'd be tons better.

Comment: That won't work if `location`, `doctorname`, or `specialtyname` are NULL

Comment: I assumed that that's what OP wanted, since in his second example `Location is not null` was in the where condition

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to do this in the code than sql as you have done.  Not really any way around it since the queries are so different, but a terse way to do it would be:

```
$loc_where = empty($loc) ? 'Location IS NOT NULL' : "Location = $loc";
$doc_where = empty($doc) ? 'AND DoctorName IS NOT NULL' : "AND DoctorName = $doc";
$spec_where = empty($spec) ? 'AND SpecialtyName IS NOT NULL' : "AND SpecialtyName = $spec";

query ... WHERE $loc_where $doc_where $spec_where
```